# Query entries by custom date field (for a particular year)

Tags: datetime, query

So I'm trying to get all entries that have a particular year assigned to a custom date field. (Could be any day/month in that year).

The custom field is `startDate` and my attempt at a query - which doesn't work - is below...

PS. `year` is a 4 digit variable set via the last segment of the url and pulled into the template as a variable, and giving you `2018`, `2019` or whatever...

```
{% set query = {
  section: 'programme',
  isOngoing: 0
} %}
{% set programmeEntries = craft.entries(query).search('startDate:' ~ year|date('Y-m-d')) %}
```

PS. I think it's more like this but I can't get the syntax right...

```
{% set query = {
  section: 'programme',
  isOngoing: 0,
  startDate: ( ['and', '>=' ~ (year~'-01-01')|date('Y')|atom, '<=' ~ (year~'-01-01')|date('Y')|date_modify('+12 months')|atom])
} %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is you're converting the date to a year string then converting that to an atom value. Just convert the date straight to an atom value:

```
{% set yearStart = "#{year}-01-01"|atom %}
{% set yearEnd = "#{year}-12-31"|atom %}

{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: "programme",
    isOngoing: 0,
    startDate: ["and", ">= #{yearStart}", "< #{yearEnd}"]
}).all %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the year vars aren't quite right though, getting this error:

DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (#{year}-01-01) at position 0 (#): Unexpected character

Comment: I don't usually use escaped variables, I was just mimicking [the docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/date-time-fields.html#settings). Anyway glad you got it working.

Comment: Oh apparently [interpolated variables only work inside double quotes](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#string-interpolation). Updated the answer to match.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: kmgdev's solution is now updated and marked correct! :)**

Fixed by slightly modifying kmgdev's solution slightly so that the year variables were interpolated correctly:

```
{% set yearStart = (year ~ '-01-01')|atom %}
{% set yearEnd = (year ~ '-12-31')|atom %}

{% set query = {
  section: 'programme',
  isOngoing: 0,
  startDate: ( ['and', '>=' ~ yearStart, '<=' ~ yearEnd])
} %}

{% set programmeEntries = craft.entries(query).all() %}
```